# Functional equation and elliptic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

I'm sorry if this question is similar to a one already asked, I'm not aware of many basic facts about elliptic curves.

Let $g$ be a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$, and $\Lambda$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that  for any $\lambda\in \Lambda$, there are constants $c_{\lambda}$ such that for   $z\in \mathbb{C}$ (out of poles) the following holds:
$$ g(z+k\lambda)=g(z)+kc_{\lambda}$$ Is it true that $g(z)=\alpha z+R(\mathcal{S})(z)$ for some elliptic function $\mathcal{S}$, polynomial $R$ and constant $\alpha$ ?

My ideas are as follow:

1. The field of meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ is $\mathbb{C}(\mathcal{S},\mathcal{S}')$ for some elliptic function $\mathcal{S}$ (for example the Weirestrass function) and $(\mathcal{S}')^2 = Q(\mathcal{S})$ for some polynomial $Q$
2. The assumption on $g$ implies that $h(z):=g'(z)$ is elliptic, that is $h(z)=P(\mathcal{S},\mathcal{S}')(z)$ by 1.
3. "Locally" (that is for $z$ near enough from a zero $z_0$ of $\mathcal{S}$, in order to find a determination of $\sqrt{Q(\mathcal{S})}$ ) :
   $$g(z)-g(z_0)=\int_{[z_0,z]} h(u) du = \int_{[z_0,z]} \mathcal{S}'(u) \frac{P(\mathcal{S},\mathcal{S}')(u)}{\sqrt{Q(\mathcal{S}(u))}} du$$
4. We may decompose the last integral into an integral with residu, giving $\alpha z$, and the remainder would be a function of $\mathcal{S}$ by an apporpriate change of variable.

I'm not sure because I have difficulties to write formally the statement 4. Is there a counterexample or do you know a classical proof otherwise ?

Thank you very much, best regards

Comment: The field of meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ should be generated by your elliptic function $S$ and $S'$, not just $S$. Moreover, if you write square brackets, you do not get the whole field, only a subring!

Comment: Thank you much for these precisions ! I made changes in my post. Do you think the statement is false ?

Answer (score 2):

The counter-example is the primitive of $\wp_\Lambda(z)$, called the Weierstrass zeta function $\zeta_\Lambda(z)$.

The derivative of $\zeta_\Lambda(z+\lambda)-\zeta_\Lambda(z)$ is identically $0$ so $\zeta_\Lambda(z+\lambda)-\zeta_\Lambda(z)$ is constant.

$\zeta_\Lambda(z)$ has only one (simple) pole on a fundamental parallelogram $P$.

So it can't be that $\zeta_\Lambda(z)=\alpha z+f(z)$  with $f$ an elliptic function, as $\int_{\partial P} \zeta_\Lambda(z)dz= 2i\pi 
 Res(\zeta_\Lambda(z),0)=2i\pi$ whereas $\int_{\partial P} f(z)dz=0$ (the opposite sides of the parallelogram are traversed in opposite direction so they cancel each other) and $\int_{\partial P}\alpha zdz = 0$.

You'll get that any $g$ satisfying your condition is of the form $$g(z)=b \zeta_\Lambda(z)+cz + f(z)$$ with $f$ elliptic.

Comment: Thank you so much ! The result you state can be obtained by similar arguments as in my post ? Could you indicate a classical reference ?

Comment: $\lambda\mapsto g(z+\lambda)-g(z)$ is a group homomorphism $\Lambda\to \Bbb{C}$, the space of such homomorphisms is a 2-dimensional $\Bbb{C}$-vector space, and taking $g_1=\zeta_\Lambda,g_2=z$ gives a basis of it.

Comment: If we replace the right handside of the condition by $$c_{\lambda}g_0$$ where g0 is a function obtained as before, i guess there is a similar construction quotienting by the subspace of these functions $g_0$ to obtain an injection to $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\Lambda,Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\Lambda,\mathbb{C}))$ whis is now $\mathbb{C}^4$.  Does $\zeta$ admit a primitive?